# Concept for adding reminders

Tags: usability, web-app, dynamic-ui

I'm remaking some code for a survey-system I'm the maintainer of. And one of the problems is adding reminders for the survey invites.

> [image]
>
> [image]

I made this: http://www.codepen.io/cwattengard/pen/HCrvx

I have adapted it slightly for the codepen since the original has some prefilled data coming from an ASP-codeblock. But for the codepen demo I've prefilled only one reminder (as you must have atleast one). I'm not sure if this solution is quite good UX though.

Some more metadata: There is a maximum of 5 reminders. You can only delete the last reminder at every point in time. You can not delete the first reminder (since it's compulsory).

Comment: What exactly is it that you want help with on this? What isn't providing the best User Experience?

Comment: Hmm.. I se I may have formulated it rather poorly. I believe my solution isn't providing the best user experience and wanted input on better ways to solve the problem.

Comment: Not providing the best user experience *for what* though? For adding reminders? The fact that you have to have a minimum of 1? That there is a maximum of 5? That the buttons are generic windows controls? It's not clear what exactly you have a problem with here.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the reminders are sent via email and that a survey will expire after a defined period, likely 30 days? The intent is to remind someone that you want their feedback and to encourage them to complete the survey?

This might not address the exact question, but I would take a step back and determine whether it makes sense to provide a user with all of this functionality and forcing them to think. Can you embed a best practice?

If it's a 30 day window in which they have to complete the survey, I would predefine my reminder rules for 5 reminders.

Reminder 1: 2 days after the survey is originally created

Reminder 2: 1 week after the survey is originally created

Reminder 3: 2 weeks after the survey is originally created

Reminder 4: 3 weeks after the survey is originally created

Reminder 5: the day before the survey expires

With this in place, you could potentially eliminate the need for a user to think through this, eliminate the need for training and support, and likely increase survey response rates.

Comment: +1 Though I would use such a "common" schedule to populate the dialog so users would only have to hit enter in most cases, but can make adjustments when desired.